# discord.py join a game command

Tags: python, discord.py, command

I want to make that when a second player joins the game with %tttjoin the game started. I tried my idea but i dont really know how to do this so I set my Player2 to True. And when someone use the command %tttjoin p2 set to False. And then with the line "if p2 is False:" the game starts. But this function isnt working and I do not know how my idea work... I hope someone knows how to do.. Also I do not get any errors yet. The game works fine without any errors. When I write %ttt the bot sends the message but when someone join with %tttjoin nothing happens. My mistake has to be the line "if p2 is False" but I dont know what I have to change.‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎

```
   async def tttjoin(self, ctx):
        global p2
        global p2name
        p2 = ctx.author
        p2 = False
        p2name = ctx.author.name

    @commands.command(aliases=["tiktaktoe", "ttt"])
    async def tictactoe(self, ctx):
        global player1
        global player2
        global p2
        global turn
        global gameOver
        global count
        player1 = ctx.author
        player2 = p2
        p1name = ctx.author.name
        msg = await ctx.send(f"<%tttjoin> um mitzuspielen. \n Player 1: {p1name} Player 2: / ")
        if p2 is False:
            await msg.edit(f"Player 1: {p1name} Player 2: {p2name} ")
            if gameOver:
                global board
                board = [":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                         ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                         ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:"]
                turn = ""
                gameOver = False
                count = 0

                line = ""
                for x in range(len(board)):
                    if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                        line += " " + board[x]
                        await ctx.send(line)
                        line = ""
                    else:
                        line += " " + board[x]

                num = random.randint(1, 2)
                if num == 1:
                    turn = player1
                    await ctx.send(f"{player1.mention} fängt an!")
                elif num == 2:
                    turn = player2
                    await ctx.send(f"{player2.mention} fängt an!")

            else:
                await ctx.send("Es wird bereits gespielt! Bitte wartet bis das Spiel fertig ist!")

    @commands.command()
    async def place(self, ctx, pos: int = None):
        global turn
        global player1
        global player2
        global board
        global count

        if pos is None:
            await ctx.send("Du musst eine Position wählen!")

        if not gameOver:
            mark = ""
            if turn == ctx.author:
                if turn == player1:
                    mark = ":regional_indicator_x:"
                elif turn == player2:
                    mark = ":o2:"
                if 0 < pos < 10:
                    if board[pos - 1] == ":white_large_square:":
                        board[pos -1] = mark
                        count += 1

                        line = ""
                        for x in range(len(board)):
                            pass
                        checkWinner(winningC, mark)
                        if gameOver:
                            await ctx.send(f"{mark} hat gewonnen!")
                        elif count >= 9:
                            await ctx.send("Unentschieden")


                        if turn == player1:
                            turn = player2
                        elif turn == player2:
                            turn = player1

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_role("Admin")
    async def tttquit(self, ctx):
        global gameOver
        global p2
        p2 = True
        gameOver = True
        await ctx.send("Das Spiel wurde beendet!")‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at a computer currently but it looks like the line `if p2 is False:` is in fact causing the problem as the function will reach this point before the second player has a chance to call the the `tttjoin` function meaning the code will pass right to over it to the `else` at the bottom.

To fix this you could maybe use a while loop so the code will only move forward when `p2 == False`.
Something like:

```
global x
while x:
   if not(p2):
       await msg.edit(f"Player 1: {p1name} Player 2: {p2name} ")
      x = False
```

Hope this makes sense :)
P.s I haven't tested it as I'm not at my computer so I'm not certain. I may edit the solution when I'm back if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thank You, ur method was not exactly working but with that I found a way to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I let the %ttt code end after the bot gets the first player. Then in %tttjoin I checked if player2 == True and set him to False then I checked if player2 == False: and copy and paste the code from %ttt.

````
    async def tictactoe(self, ctx):
        global player1
        global player2
        global p2
        global p1
        global turn
        global gameOver
        global count
        global x
        global p1fullname
        global msg
        p1 = ctx.author
        player1 = p1
        p1fullname = ctx.author.name
        if gameOver:
            global board
            board = [":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                     ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                     ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:"]
            turn = ""
            gameOver = False
            count = 0

            line = ""
            for x in range(len(board)):
                if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                    line += " " + board[x]
                    await ctx.send(line)
                    line = ""
                else:
                    line += " " + board[x]

    @commands.command()
    async def place(self, ctx, pos: int = None):
        global turn
        global player1
        global player2
        global board
        global count
        global p1name

        if pos is None:
            await ctx.send("Du musst eine Position wählen!")

        if not gameOver:
            mark = ""
            if turn == ctx.author:
                if turn == player1:
                    mark = ":regional_indicator_x:"
                elif turn == player2:
                    mark = "️"
                if 0 < pos < 10:
                    if board[pos - 1] == ":white_large_square:":
                        board[pos - 1] = mark
                        count += 1

                        line = ""
                        for x in range(len(board)):
                            if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                                line += " " + board[x]
                                await ctx.send(line)
                                line = ""
                            else:
                                line += " " + board[x]

                        checkWinner(winningC, mark)
                        if gameOver:
                            await ctx.send(f"{mark} hat gewonnen!")
                        elif count >= 9:
                            await ctx.send("Unentschieden")

                        if turn == player1:
                            turn = player2
                        elif turn == player2:
                            turn = player1

                    else:
                        await ctx.send("Dieses Feld ist bereits belegt!")
                else:
                    await ctx.send("Du musst ein Feld zwischen 1 und 9 wählen!")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Du bist noch nicht dran!")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Du musst zu erst ein neues Spiel starten!")

    @commands.command(aliases=["tttj", "jointtt"])
    async def tttjoin(self, ctx):
        global p2
        global player2
        global p2name
        global p2check
        global turn

        print("Hiii")
        if p2check is True:
            print("Something")
            p2 = ctx.author
            p2check = False
            p2name = ctx.author.name

            if p2check == False:
                print("YES")
                player2 = p2
                num = random.randint(1, 2)
                if num == 1:
                    turn = player1
                    await ctx.send(f"{player1.mention} fängt an!")
                elif num == 2:
                    turn = player2
                    await ctx.send(f"{player2.mention} fängt an!")
                    return

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_role("Admin")
    async def tttquit(self, ctx):
        global gameOver
        global p2
        p2 = True
        gameOver = True
        await ctx.send("Das Spiel wurde beendet!")```
````